# Convert characters with combining diacritics to pre-composed characters

Tags: text, typography, software-recommendation, unicode

I had a large amount of Greek with an audio file of people reading it.  I broke both up into phrases to save as pronunciation guides.  Unfortunately, the text used combining diacritics, and the audio program converted them into precomposed characters to create the file names.  Result, the file names as referred to in text are not the actual file names.

Before I write a long list of substitution regexes, I'm wondering if there is open source code already available to do such a mass conversion.  Obviously, such code is already in the audio program (Amadeus Pro).